# Why is Google truncating my URLs? (using Zend framework)

Tags: zend-framework, url, seo

I run a site called anecdotage.com (bunch of funny stories about famous ppl).

We just moved to a new platform (socialengine 4, Zend framework).
Our URLs are new & google has been indexing them, which is great!
But I just noticed that it's ignoring the most iportant part of the URL... not so great!

It still works, but I'm worried about our page rank.

EG:
System URL:
http://www.anecdotage.com/articles/7994/allman-brothers-foot-shootin-morons

Google URL:
http://www.anecdotage.com/articles/7994/

[You can see here:
https://www.google.com.mx/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=site:anecdotage.com%2Farticles&oq=site:anecdotage.com%2Farticles

We submitted a txt sitemap, with complete links. Why is Google doing this? Does it matter for SEO?

Also:
When I follow a link from google, it does this:
http://www.anecdotage.com/articles/7994/#.UHOF_JhX3ZI

Can anyone explain  what's going on?

Comment: Are you sure that the sitemap you sent had the extended URLS?  Are you sure it didn't have the short ones first?  As long as the contents of the URL are on the page, I wouldn't sweat the SEO aspect - Google's probably smarter than you are.

Comment: Oh, I think we did replace an older sitemap. Will wait & see if it's OK. Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

Both urls have identical content.

To solve this you could had canonical link in the header pointing for the desired url you wish goole to index:

<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.anecdotage.com/articles/7994/allman-brothers-foot-shootin-morons" />

More details at [google blog](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.pt/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html)